# Can we prevent the user from zooming out in googlemaps

Tags: android, google-maps

I have 2 questions:

Is it possible to prevent the user from **only** zooming out and we keep the zooming in?

Can we control to which extent the user can zoom in and out on the google map?

Answer (score 0):

You can [disable the Zoom Gestures](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/interactivity#zoom_gestures) on the map, but you have to disable any on screen Zoom controls too (the plus and minus sign at the top left usually) since disabling the first does not disable the second.

Then, if I'm not mistaken any action the user does over the map will be propagated to the holding view below it so you can capture these actions and propagate them to the MapView programmatically.

E.g. if your MapView is inside a LinearLayout, capture all user interaction for the LinearLayout, see what the user did (e.g. pinched in) and zoom in the map programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

Or as @hasMobi answered. First you disable the zoom controls and then provide a Button, whenever the Button clicked you perform only zoom in action. If the zoom reaches your max ZoomLevel then disable the Button.